# optional String array JSON

Tags: swift

I use the youtube API to get the ID of the video
With the JSON function I add it to the array
but when i put the video id from array i get me error

This is the code:

the struct:

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let items: [Item]
}

// MARK: - Item
struct Item: Decodable {
    let id: ID
}

// MARK: - ID
struct ID: Decodable {
    let videoId: String?
}

// MARK: - PageInfo
struct PageInfo: Decodable {
    let totalResults, resultsPerPage: Int
}
```

the code:

```
    var videos: Item?
@IBOutlet var playerView: YTPlayerView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    playerView.delegate = self
    playerView.load(withVideoId: videos?.id.videoId) // HERE THE ERROR
    // Initialization code
    }
```

this error:

> Option of the optional 'String?' The engraving should be turned off to a 'string' entry

Comment: Please edit your question and add the json returned by the API and how you are decoding it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `String` and not `String?` Try:

```
if let id = videos?.id.videoId {
    playerView.load(withVideoId: id) // HERE THE ERROR
    // Initialization code
    }
}
```

Reason: As your `videos` and `id` vars are Optionals (`?` at the end) you need to check if it is not `nil` befor accessing it.

Comment: I get Same error

Comment: Thank you, now the error I disappear but now I don't see the video, I checked the array and it appended all video id but now videoid.videoId return nil and not show videos..

Comment: @WarRock  You probably got multiple issues here. Without further info it will be hard to answer this.